# JavaClassStatics / StaticClass, how to use an object of that type?

Tags: java, javascript, enums

I am having a really hard time trying to use such object.

In my case it is holding an static enum from:

```
obj = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByMimeType("text/javascript").
eval("Java.type('"+((Class<Enum>)enumClass).getName()+"');");
```

now I need to be able to do something with `obj` from within java, not only from within a bind in javascript (where it would work easily).

Can I cast it in some way to access the enum reference it is holding from within java? I would like to access the `.values()` of such enum but I dont know if it is possible that way.

Comment: @Basilevs thx! https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7865/112610

Answer (score 0):

for enums, was quite simple, using javascript itself:
`eval("Java.type('"+((Class<Enum>)enumClass).getName()+"').values();");`

I couldnt find a way to use the StaticClass object, but at least for enums it will be easy now.